# Turn off display without screenlock

Tags: display, command-line

Is there a terminal command?

For istance, when i type:

```
sleep 1 && xset dpms force off
```

It turns off the display but enables automatically the screenlock (that instead I'd like to keep just when the computer is inactive).

Answer (score 2):

`xset dpms force off`
Also disable "Lock after screen turns off" in System Settings > Security & Privacy > Locking.

Comment: When I run that command then the screen automatically locks but if I disable "Lock after screen turns off" I would lose the locking during inactive mode

Comment: Then don't disable "Lock on sleep", also in System Settings > Security & Privacy > Locking.

Comment: Yeah I don't disable it, for inactive I mean that the screen turns off after some minutes and locks automatically

Comment: Set the minutes after you want to turn off display and lock automatically in System Settings > Power.

Comment: No, I explain better. I'd like write a command in terminal so that just the screen turns off immediately (ex. in a moment I'm studying on paper) and when I move/click the mouse it turns on. I prefer a command so that the screen turns off and locks automatically just in case I'm too long time far from the computer (so I can't set too few minutes). From the other answer it seems that I have a kind of bug that I don't know how to solve.

Comment: You don't have any bug. For the screen to turn off and lock automatically, use `dm-tool lock `. You can also add this as a custom keyboard shortcut, but it's already there under the power button.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the lowest brightness level on elementary turns off the display. [This question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1311/8931) covers how to change brightness using command line.

Comment: I tried both methods with brightness to 0 but it just decreases to zero the brightness leaving the screen turned on

Comment: That might be a bug in your system. Not only elementary turns off display for the lowest brightness, but also Ubuntu and most, if not all its derivatives. Have you tried the lowest brightness using GUI? Does it turn off display?

Comment: Do you mean with xrandr? It decreases the brightness to 0 doesn't turn off the screen

Comment: No. I mean with using your mouse or keyboard with the brightness slider like so https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHRQG.png

Comment: Sorry, no it doesn't work (and also doesn't reach the 0 brightness like the other methods)

Comment: I gave been using elementary since Freya beta on different computers. It's always been that way, the lowest brightness turns off screen. I could still listen to music, and even type without seeing what I'm doing. Video playback doesn't stop, it's simply the screen that is turned off, nothing else. Your issue is a little strange.

Comment: Have you tried setting brightness value to -1?

Comment: I really don't know why it doesn't work, anyway yeah I also tried that and it reverses the colours (like a negative)

Comment: Wow! This is definitely not the solution for your specific problem.